# How to tell Xamarin Forms that image should be in column 0 of 3 where there is no content in cols 1 and 2

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using XF to design a simple login page and I got most controls to where I want but I am struggling with an image that I want to go into the top left corner.

If I specify the image as follows

```
<Image Source="logo.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"></Image>
```

Then the above makes look ok size wise but it puts the image in column 3 as oppose to column 0 where I want it, I understand why but I don't understand how I can place it in column 0 when cols 1 and 2 don't have content in there, if I specify grid.column="0" then it fills up the entire screen as it doesn't know cols 1 and 2 and I cannot find anyway to say that I want the image in columns 0 out of 3 so to say.

my entire page looks like this and works fine apart from the top image as I described above that I want in 0 out of 3 columns

```
<ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image Source="logo.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                </Image>
            </Grid>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Spacing="10" x:Name="MainPageLayout">
                    <Label Text="Username"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    </Label>
                    <Entry 
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           x:Name="userNameTxt">
                    </Entry>

                    <Label Text="Password"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    </Label>
                    <Entry 
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           IsPassword="True"
                           x:Name="passWordTxt">
                    </Entry>

                    <Label Text="Store Id"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    </Label>
                    <Entry 
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           x:Name="storeIdTxt">
                    </Entry>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Button Text="Login" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                                x:Name="loginBtn"
                                Clicked="LoginBtnClicked">
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the picture to the right of the screen, I want it to the left in column 0 of 3

[image]

Comment: What you want to do can you please update question and add some screen so its better to understand.

Comment: You need to set rowdefinition and columndefinition of the grid

Comment: How do I set that rowdef and col def ?

Comment: Add screenshot of design your requirement I will help you to set your grid.

Comment: You can do it with or without grid please look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  try below code there are no need to grid for that

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10" x:Name="MainPageLayout">
    <Image Source="logo.png"  HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" >
    </Image>

        <Label Text="Username"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        </Label>
        <Entry 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               x:Name="userNameTxt">
        </Entry>

        <Label Text="Password"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        </Label>
        <Entry 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               IsPassword="True"
               x:Name="passWordTxt">
        </Entry>

        <Label Text="Store Id"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        </Label>
        <Entry 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               x:Name="storeIdTxt">
        </Entry>
        <Button Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="200"
                x:Name="loginBtn"
                Clicked="LoginBtnClicked">
        </Button>

</StackLayout>
```